# How to best prevent running async method again before it completes?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've got this pattern for preventing calling into an async method before it has had a chance to complete previously.

My solution involving needing a flag, and then needing to lock around the flag, feels pretty verbose. Is there a more natural way of achieving this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object SyncIsFooRunning = new object();
    private bool IsFooRunning { get; set;}

    public async Task FooAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            lock(SyncIsFooRunning)
            {
                if(IsFooRunning)
                    return;

                IsFooRunning = true;
            }

            // Use a semaphore to enforce maximum number of Tasks which are able to run concurrently.
            var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
            var trackedTasks = new List<Task>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

                trackedTasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // DoTask();
                    semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }));
            }

            // Using await makes try/catch/finally possible.
            await Task.WhenAll(trackedTasks);
        }
        finally
        {
            lock(SyncIsFooRunning)
            {
                IsFooRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `lock()`, you can use `Interlocked.Exchange()`.

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: @Slaks - Interlocked.Exchange doesn't support bools. I changed the code to async Task, but it didn't require any other changes. Seems a bit odd that all the return types are still valid for Task?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` if you prefer:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _flag;

    public async Task FooAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _flag, 1, 0) == 1)
            {
                return;
            }

            // do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _flag, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

That said, I think it's overkill. Nothing wrong with using `lock` in this type of scenario, especially if you don't expect a lot of contention on the method. What I *do* think would be better is to wrap the method so that the caller can always `await` on the result, whether a new asynchronous operation was started or not:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private Task _task;

    public Task FooAsync()
    {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return _task != null ? _task : (_task = FooAsyncImpl());
            }
    }

    public async Task FooAsyncImpl()
    {
        try
        {
            // do async stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (_lock) _task = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the comments, you say this:

> Seems a bit odd that all the return types are still valid for Task?

Not clear to me what you mean by that. In your method, the only valid return types would be `void` and `Task`. If your `return` statement(s) returned an actual value, you'd have to use `Task<T>` where `T` is the type returned by the return statement(s).

Comment: You can simplify `return _task != null ? _task : (_task = FooAsyncImpl());` to `return _task ?? (_task = FooAsyncImpl());`.